# How do I include a statically linked library in my Eclipse C++ project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I have an open-source library that's distributed in source form. After I run the Makefile, I end up with a `.h` file and a `.a` file that I then want to include in a project that I'm working on. I'm familiar with how I can add these by editing a Makefile manually or by invoking the compiler from the command line, but I'm not sure how I can add these to my Eclipse C++ project, created using the [CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/).

I'm currently using Eclipse Indigo. I found some instructions for older versions of Eclipse, but the menus aren't what are described. I poked around a bit, and didn't see anything familiar.

Answer (score 8):

right click on the project name in the project explorer with the project being opened, select project properties. Then select C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> includes -> GNU C++ and add the path to your header file. You should do the same for you library under : C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Libraries -> Add , and add your library file path.

Answer (score 7):

How do I add an external library to my C++ project?

Go to Your Project's Properties by right clicking on project's name and selecting properties. Click on "C/C++ Build". Under Settings->Tool Settings Tab, click on GCC C Linker / Libraries. Then add a library and a search path.

Comment: Is that accurate for the latest CDT? I don't see the Tool Settings Tab. There is one under C/C++ Build > Settings, but I don't see a Directories there at all. The second paragraph is also not correct or missing information - under Miscellaneous for the linker I'm using, there are Other options and Other objects, and I'm not sure which one should be used. I'll try the third option, next.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Sorry, wiki was too old. I've updated. My Eclipse version is 3.7.1

Comment: I'm about to leave work, so I can't try on what I was trying to do, but I do have a project at home I can continue to try with. The only problem is that the Tool Settings tab is under C/C++ Build -> Settings and not directly under C/C++ Build. I'm also assuming that GCC might be Cygwin (since I'm using the Cygwin toolchain, not the GCC toolchain). Everything else lines up, though, and makes sense to me. I'll follow up either later tonight if this works at home or tomorrow once I have time to experiment with this at work.