# eclipse-cdt how to link with static library

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Fist i am confused should i set libraries under Linker/Libraries or to set them under "path and symbol". i think that they are the same. am i correct?

any way for my question - i need to link static library , so i tried few things:

**First try** I try to add gtest (this is the library) and gtest path in the link library.
in this way its compiled and linked correct , but failed in runtime , because when it tried to load shared library (**i want static library !**) error is

> error while loading shared libraries: libgtest.so.0

**Second try** - I try do define it in path and symbol add to libraries the complete path '/root/workspace/gmock/gtest/lib/.lib/libgtest.a' . in this case i got error in the linkage :

```
g++ -L/root/workspace/gmock/lib/.libs -L/root/workspace/gmock/gtest/lib/.libs -o "playground"  ./src/p.o ./src/playground.o   -lpthread -l/root/workspace/gmock/gtest/lib/.lib/libgtest.a -l/root/workspace/gmock/lib/.lib/libgmock.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/root/workspace/gmock/gtest/lib/.lib/libgtest.a
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332460/how-do-i-include-a-statically-linked-library-in-my-eclipse-c-project) dosnt give an answer and not explain how you define differently linked against static vs shared.

Thank you

Comment: did you try -L/root/workspace/gmock/gtest/lib/.lib/ -lgtest.a ?

Comment: Yep, try it. still get  -"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest.a". as far as i know the file name is libgtest.a and you should write gtest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After lot of research and not related answer. found it!!!
I found it in [this useful link for eclipse-cdt](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234122/Spring2012/en/faq_Working%20with%20Eclipse%20CDT.html)

Apparently the library need to exist in the workspace.

Comment: Despite adding the project to the "Library search path" and adding the library name without the prefix "lib" and suffix ".a" to the "Libraries" in "GCC C++ Linker" I found necessary as well adding the referenced project to the include path (GCC C++ Compiler --> Includes --> Include paths)

Comment: it seems this still works with eclipse luna, but how can I link .so file? same way?

Answer (score 4):

Add library path/file to: Properties - C/C++ Build - Settings - GCC C++ Linker - Miscellaneous - Other objects

Answer (score 1):

I built the Botan cryptography library as a static library, for reasons I don't want to go into here, and when I followed all the steps on the interwebs, add the library paths and specify the library name without "lib" and ".a", my project built just fine, however, when I ran it, I kept getting "The program terminated unexpectedly" (or similar) errors. Finally I figured out how to fix it. In Menu Bar, go to Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross G++ Linker and add `-static` between `${COMMAND}` and `${FLAGS}`, so the whole line looks like:

```
${COMMAND} -static ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

Yours may vary. I'm using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), with mingw-w64 mingw-builds project w/gcc 4.9.2 on Windows 8.1.