# Using LAPACK with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, lapack

I am building a project using Eigen in C++ Eclipse. I have been trying to figure out how to use LAPACK in Eigen but I didn't go far, I searched the web but I almost found nothing. The only references I found are:

1) LAPACK-Eigen: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Lapack

2) LAPACK build and test guide: https://gcc.gnu.org/testing/testing-lapack.html

Neither of them was useful for me, I have no experience with that and they are very brief on the other hand. I would deeply appreciate any help or if anyone could point me to a nice tutorial.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'use LAPACK in Eigen'? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to link LAPACK to a C++ project on Eclipse that uses Eigen, i.e. I want to be able to use the methods declared in LAPACK, maybe it's better to ask how to link LAPACK to a C++ project on Eclipse.

Comment: If that's you question, then the first link is your friend. If it's how link to a library, that's not specific to LAPACK and that's covered in a plethora of questions (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332460/how-do-i-include-a-statically-linked-library-in-my-eclipse-c-project)).