# How do I link static libraries in Eclipse CDT (Windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I'm tring to link `glew` library to my project, and I tried literally everything I could find over the internet.

I got MinGW compiller.

I downloaded windows binaries for library and put them in `includes` and `libs` in the root directory of my project respectively.

I set in Project Properties -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries in `library search path` `${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/libs}` and `glew32s` and `glfw3dll` in `libraries`

I set in Project Properties -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Compiller -> Includes my include folder

I added in Project Properties -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Compiller -> Miscellaneous`-std=gnu++0x` flag

[image: project tree]
[image: includes]
[image: libraries]

I'm trying to make this work

```
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
       glfwPollEvents();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

But it seems like Eclipse just ignores it. I have NO OUTPUT, it jus says "Terminated". I tried to put a beakpoint but debugger is just ignores it. What am I doing wrong and why is it so RIDICULOUSLY HARD, to just link a library?

UPD:

Got some strange exit code `-1073741515`

here's a link to a video
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7kcwczv1zmmjfu/eclipse.webm?dl=0

Comment: I kinda agree that libraly management in C++ in rather troublesome, but what do you mean "no output"? Does your executable compile? You should've posted build log here.

Comment: It seems that it builds and compiles. No errors, no warnings. Literally abolutely nothing. The console is empty. The only one strange thing I just noticed is program exit code, it looks kinda odd: `-1073741515`. And I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: Console should not be empty. Even successful build produces quite a lot of text. Also are you sure that static libraries you are trying to link match to compiler version you are using?

Comment: I would love to share console content, but it's just blank. I use same libraries with CLion, and Clion compiles the code just fine. Both Eclipse and CLion uses MinGW compiler and *.lib libraries.

Comment: @VTT updated post, added link to the video

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332460/how-do-i-include-a-statically-linked-library-in-my-eclipse-c-project

Comment: @I-V added screenshots. Still no luck

Comment: Do you do a clean before the build?